# Mystery linebreak when generating meta description

Tags: php

I have this function which **cuts a string into a number of characters without chopping any word**. I use it for the **meta_description of a page**.

```
function meta_description_function($text, $length){ // Meta Description Function
        if(strlen($text) > $length) {
            $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', $length));
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

I pull the content from a wordpress post:

```
$content = $content_post->post_content;
```

I strip the tags from the content:

```
$content = strip_tags($content);
```

And I aplly my function to the content:

```
$meta_description = meta_description_function($content, 140);
```

**The problem is when the $content is like this:**

```
<p>Hello I am sentence one inside my own paragraph.</p>

<p>Hello I am sentence two inside my own paragraph.</p>
```

**After applying the content and I echo $meta_description I get the sentences in different lines, something like this:**

```
<meta name="description" content="Hello I am sentence one inside my own paragraph.
**<i get a space here!>**
Hello I am sentence two inside my own paragraph." />
```

Why does this empty space appear if I have used strip tags, what can I do to make it disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trim the whitespace, and remove line breaks. then strip the tags. **all in one line!**

`$content = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($content) ) );` **Note:** \s takes care of a few more cases than just line breaks and spaces.. also tabs and form feeds, etc.

[DEMO](http://www.tehplayground.com/#M1z2XguEs)

Answer (score 2):

You get the linebreak because you have a linebreak in your HTML too. `striptags` will remove all tags, but not linebreaks.

To remove them you can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace)/[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str-replace). Just remove the `\n` out of the string.

Comment: Ty, something like this? $meta_description = trim($meta_description, " \n");

Comment: @user1383036 I think it is better to use `$text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $text);` because it also removes the `\r` (another type of linebreak)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code is actually displaying the newline character from the source:

```
<p>Hello I am sentence one inside my own paragraph.</p>

<p>Hello I am sentence two inside my own paragraph.</p>
```

The blank line between the two is actually placed there with two newlines, carriage returns, or both.  You can probably do something like this to get rid of it:

```
$text = str_replace("\n", "", $text);
$text = str_replace("\r", "", $text);
```

Hope that helps!  Note- you may want to replace with a space instead of empty string.

Comment: or use an array as argument: `$text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $text);`

Comment: It works but if I use this $meta_description = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), " ", $meta_description); I get 4 empty spaces. Why? Ty very much

Comment: Because it's probably got \n\r for each new line.  I believe that's a Windows thing.  Using the array replace you could do this: str_replace(array("\n\r","\n", "\r", "  "), " ", $meta_description);
The last one "  " has two spaces in it, so that way if you have two spaces side by side anywhere they'd get replaced by one.

Answer (score 1):

`$content = str_replace( "\n", "", strip_tags($content) );`

Comment: Better to replace with a space than nothing, in case you end up with `Somethinglike this`